# openlayers - filter mapserver WMS with runtime substitution

Tags: openlayers, wms, mapserver, filter

I am new to runtime substitutions with Mapserver.

I have a Openlayers map where I show a mapserver WMS.

Now, I'd like the user to choose a value from a dropdown list, and filter the WMS with his/her choice.

The LAYER of my mapfile looks like:

**mapfile**

```
LAYER
  NAME zone
  TYPE POLYGON
  CONNECTIONTYPE ogr
  ...
  FILTER ('[vitigni]' = '%vitigni%')
  VALIDATION
    "vitigni" "^[a-zA-Z\-]+$"
  END
END
```

In my HTML I have:

**myol.html**

```
var wmsSource1 = new ol.source.ImageWMS({
    url: 'http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserver/mapserv.exe?map=//nbgis01/mapserver/umbe/mapfile/test10_runtimesubstitution.map',
    params: {
        'LAYERS': 'cantine',
        'CRS': 'EPSG:3857',
        'BBOX': '870510,5559757,1360294,5868524',
        'WIDTH': '800',
        'HEIGHT': '500',
        'FORMAT': 'image/png'
    },
    projection: 'EPSG:3857',
    serverType: 'mapserver',
    imageExtent: imageExtent
});
```

What is the way to filter this WMS with (e.g.) a form?

I tried with the below code, but I only got *mapserv(): Web application error. Traditional BROWSE mode requires a TEMPLATE in the WEB section, but none was provided.*

**myol.html** (again)

```
<div class="query">
    <form name="mapserv" method="GET" action="http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserver/mapserv.exe?">
        <input type="hidden" name="map" value="//nbgis01/mapserver/umbe/mapfile/test10_runtimesubstitution.map">
        <select name="vitigni">
            <option value="Groppello">Groppello</option>
        </select>
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Click Me">
    </form>
</div>
```

When I submit the form the request generated is *http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserver/mapserv.exe?map=%2F%2Fnbgis01%2Fmapserver%2Fumbe%2Fmapfile%2Ftest10_runtimesubstitution.map&vitigni=Groppello*.

I need the page to display my openalyer map with my WMS filtered with `"vitigni"="Groppello"`.

Just as a sidenote: the map with and without filter works correctly. If I display the whole layers I can visualize everything correctly. If I copy the request and append `&vitigni=Groppello`, I am able to visualize only the layer I want, but in another webpage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to do it!

Basically:

1. I defined the filter in the mapfile
2. I created the dropdown with some possible values to pass to the filter
3. With jQuery I get the selected value, and pass it to the 'params' option of the my wms source with the [`updateParams()`](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.source.ImageWMS.html#updateParams) method.

**mapfile**

```
LAYER
  NAME zone
  TYPE POLYGON
  CONNECTIONTYPE ogr
  ...
  FILTER ('[vitigni]' = '%vitigni%')
  VALIDATION
    "vitigni" "^[a-zA-Z]+$"
  END
END
```

**myol.html**

```
<!-- the dropdown list -->

<select class="query">
    <option value="All layers" selected>All layers</option>
    <option value="Groppello">Groppello</option>
</select>

<script>

// the Mapserver WMS source

var wmsSource2 = new ol.source.ImageWMS({
    url: 'https://192.168.0.100/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=/home/umberto/Documents/apps/projects/wineshire/mapfile/mapfile/test11_linux.map',
    params: {
        'LAYERS': 'zone',
        'vitigni': 'Chardonnay, Pinot bianco, Riesling renano, Rieslin',
        'CRS': 'EPSG:3857',
        'BBOX': '884148,5588735,1172521,5764462',
        'WIDTH': '800',
        'HEIGHT': '500',
        'FORMAT': 'image/png'
    },
    projection: 'EPSG:3857',
    serverType: 'mapserver',
    imageExtent: imageExtent
});

// the dynamic filter!!!

$('.query').on('change', function() {
    var filter = $(this).val();
    var params = wmsSource2.getParams();
    params.vitigni = filter;
    wmsSource2.updateParams(params);
    });
```